# Google Closure Compiler breaks script on Advanced Optimization

Tags: google-closure-compiler

I'm trying to build a google chrome extension and finally using the google closure compiler on advanced optimization but it ends up breaking the script and introduces undefined 'e' and so on.

On Simple Optimization it works, wondering what might be causing the script to break and whether there's anything I shouldn't do in my code that ends up being incompatible in Advanced optimization mode.

Comment: If you can give a small snippet of code that demonstrates the problem it will be a lot easier to help you. However, https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/limitations may provide some helpful hints.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to workaround renaming of object properties in Closure Compiler?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15698631/how-to-workaround-renaming-of-object-properties-in-closure-compiler)

Answer (score 0):

I have found that with the closure compiler advanced optimizations, it will remove variables shared between the chrome extension background page and extension client UI's like browser action or options pages.  To solve that, I replace declarations on the background page, such as this (meant to be found via `chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().foo` in, say, the options page).

```
var foo = { };
```

with

```
window.foo = { };
```

and then the name is minified but the same name is shared between background page and options page.

For a bit more info see my blog post [How to use closure compiler advanced optimizations on chrome extension](http://erikeidt.blogspot.com/2016/08/how-to-use-closure-compiler-advanced.html).